# How to boost Decimal module in Python

Tags: python, decimal, cython

I have written a code using the Python module Decimal, but it takes some time to be executed.

So, I would like to boost it. After profiling it, I’ve seen that a function could be improved.

Consequently, I have two questions:

1. Is the cdecimal module the same as the decimal module ?
2. If not, how could I install the cdecimal module on my mac? « pip3 install pypi-cdecimal » gives the following error:

```
    Collecting pypi-cdecimal
      Using cached             https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/3e/0e8408545ef9bca6e11956c1e78215b820f0193669afe8750f9cbaa054d1/pypi-cdecimal-2.3.tar.gz

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/lf/v8d843ms57dd27cslfdcbrlc0000gn/T/pip-install-wvun3np6/pypi-cdecimal/setup.py", line 426, in <module>
        ext_modules = [cdecimal_ext(MACHINE)]
      File "/private/var/folders/lf/v8d843ms57dd27cslfdcbrlc0000gn/T/pip-install-wvun3np6/pypi-cdecimal/setup.py", line 315, in cdecimal_ext
        config_vars = configure(machine, cc, py_size_t)
      File "/private/var/folders/lf/v8d843ms57dd27cslfdcbrlc0000gn/T/pip-install-wvun3np6/pypi-cdecimal/setup.py", line 230, in configure
        os.chmod("./configure", 0x1ed) # pip removes execute permissions.
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './configure'
```

3. Is it possible to cythonize my code? Could me cythonize using Decimal variables?
4. If any of these could be helpful, should I have to switch to numpy?

Comment: Why are you using Decimal if numpy would work?

Comment: Thanks Mark,I’m not sure of the precision of floating point I could have in Numpy. I need to compute numbers with 300 decimals, for example

Comment: For 300 decimals numpy wouldn't be close to good enough. If the precision is fixed then you could use integers and scale them yourself but I think that's how Decimal works already.

Comment: You're looking for 300 *digit* precision? The machine you are using will most definitely be the upper bound in this case

Comment: IIRC, the memory required to store `n` bits goes like `bits ~ log2(10**num_digits)`

Comment: @Mark, the number of decimal is not really fixed... Working with Decimal is actually nice, because it could be changed and 300 is absolutely reachable

Comment: @C.Nivs, yes I’m looking for 300 digits precision

Comment: `cdecimal` is the builtin implementation of `decimal` since Python 3.3, so if you are using a recent Python version you don't need to install it.

Comment: @jdehesa, thank you for this important information which answer the first two points: I’m using Python 3.6.5

Comment: @C.Nivs you can simplify that to `num_digits*log2(10)`. 300 digits is large but not outrageously so.

Comment: @MarkRansom true, rules of logs/exponents bite me again

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, `cmodule` is the version of `module` written in C (instead of pure Python). Python 3 will choose to use the `c` version automatically if it's available, and ever since CPython 3.3, `cdecimal` has been built-in.

So if you're using CPython (and if you don't know what that is then you definitely are), you're already using `cdecimal` every time you `import decimal`.

The problem is, working with 300 digits of precision is expensive. This is just a fundamental limitation. Numpy isn't optimized for that sort of thing and won't help (since none of the built-in Numpy types are capable of it). I doubt Cython will help either, since it gets its speed from using native C data types (same as Numpy). The best way to make your code run faster is to reduce that precision.

As for how to reduce precision, that depends on your problem. For example, a Naïve Bayes model might involve multiplying tiny, tiny numbers with a hundred zeroes after the decimal point before you get to anything significant. So you might think you need a `Decimal` with that many digits. In practice, you can take the logarithm and add instead of multiplying, and now your precision needs are solved while still giving the right answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Draconis. This closes questions 1, 2 and 4. It remains the third one: is it possible to cythonize a code using cDecimal module?

Comment: @MathTolliob It should work in Cython (most Python code should work unmodified) but I think it'd be difficult to set static types and get any real benefit

Comment: @DavidW The idea would be to be able to declare static type of the class Decimal, i.e. to modify a bit the source file. Do you know if it’s possible?

Comment: @MathTolliob You could try to follow [the scheme for "External Extension Types" in the documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#external-extension-types) to get at the internals. I think it would be quite a bit of work before you got any benefit from it